# copy file from executing folder and paste into installing folder in installshield( InstallScript project)

Tags: installation, setup-project, installshield, installscript

I am creating a InstallScript project in installshield 2011 and my problem is

**I want to know the path of the setup from where it is executing**

Suppose there is a folder name "project_setup" in which setup.exe and abc.txt file exist.Now at run time I want to copy abc.txt file and paste it to where the setup is installed.

**EDIT:**
Now I am able to copy the file but In my Release folder there are 2 setups

- In Disk Image/Disk1 folder (This setup Copy&Paste the .txt file and execute fine)
- other is in the Package folder (This setup dont Copy&Paste but execute fine)

So how to make setup in Single exe so that it execute as well as copy&paste .txt file also.

Comment: This is a bad practice. If a file has to be copied to install directory, it must be part of the setup project.

Comment: What can we do........this is client requirement....

Answer (score 1):

CopyFile(SRCDIR ^ "abc.txt", TARGETDIR ^ "abc.txt");

Comment: For Network Image, you need to parse PACKAGE_LOCATION with api ParsePath, then execute CopyFile.